# Top of centered DIV is cut issue if center it on screen vertically and horizontally

Tags: css

There are many ways to center a div element on screen both vertically and horizontally but none of them solved the issue that I am facing.

The problem that needs to be solved is, if height of centered div is much greater than screen height top of centered element would be cut, in this case the centered div should be aligned top, and vertical scroll bar should show up to be used. In other words the page height should be equal to centered div height.

The data provided in the div I want to place in center of screen is dynamic so I don’t know the height of the centered div but in most of the cases its height is less than the page height.

I want something like Gmail login page.

Here is code
https://jsfiddle.net/wxeecwuk/

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
```

Comment: Why dont you try height in % or vh?

Comment: % and vh both are not suitable here.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the updated answer. Hope it is helpful to you. I have updated height in `vh` i.e viewport height.

Here it will take 80% of height of any screen. whether it is mobile ipad or desktop.

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual, what is a pain do achieve with classic CSS (position: absolute, margin hacks, etc.) is a breeze with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  border: #00f solid 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container .centered {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="centered">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
```

you add this your code `max-width: 100%`

Comment: Thank you @gungor for reply, I don't need height: 200px; as my content is dynamic. In my question it is just for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**like this ?**

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
```